# Multiple docx file read collectively

Tags: python, dataframe, text, .doc

I'm trying to make a framework under which a folder will contain multiple word document which python will read collectively & would provide me an output with all the SSN in that file.

I'm done with the solution also, i.e. I'm able to build the function which provides the results, but I want to get the corresponding file name also from which the SSN is extracted.

```
#importing libraries        
import pandas as pd    
import docx2txt    

#extracting data from all the files at once    
import glob    
data = ''   
for file in glob.glob('C:/Users/d118/Desktop/Word Files/*.docx'):        
    data += docx2txt.process(file)    

#defining the function
def isSSNNumber(text):    
    if len(text) != 11:    
        return False    
    for i in range(0,3):    
        if not text[i].isdecimal():    
               return False    
    if text[3] != '-':    
           return False    
    for i in range(4,6):    
         if not text[i].isdecimal():    
            return False    
    if text[6] != '-':    
           return False    
    for i in range(7,11):    
         if not text[i].isdecimal():    
            return False    
    return True    

#using the function    
result = []    
for i in range(len(data)):    
    chunk = data[i:i+11]    
    if isSSNNumber(chunk):    
        result.append(chunk)    

#required dataframe 

df = pd.DataFrame(result)    
df
```

Now that I have my SSN extracted I also want to have corresponding file name from which they exactly belong to.

Please click below to see the output.

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIuMi.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
def isSSNNumber(text, file):    
    if len(text) != 11:    
        return False    
    for i in range(0,3):    
        if not text[i].isdecimal():    
               return False    
    if text[3] != '-':    
           return False    
    for i in range(4,6):    
         if not text[i].isdecimal():    
            return False    
    if text[6] != '-':    
           return False    
    for i in range(7,11):    
         if not text[i].isdecimal():    
            return False  
    print(file)
    return True
```

main:

```
for file in glob.glob('C:/Users/d118/Desktop/Word Files/*.docx'):
    data = docx2txt.process(file)
    result = []
    for i in range(len(data)):
        chunk = data[i:i + 11]
        if isSSNNumber(chunk, file):
            result.append(chunk)
```